# What is the meaning of these summations?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Image1]

Am I meant to add the two summations together, or multiply them? If the latter, what makes it any different from an outer product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use $3$ instead of $100$, for the sake of the argument. $$\sum_{i = 1}^3\sum_{j = 1}^3x_iy_j = \sum_{i = 1}^3(x_iy_1+x_iy_2+x_iy_3) \\= x_1y_1+x_1y_2+x_1y_3+x_2y_1+x_2y_2+x_2y_3+x_3y_1+x_3y_2+x_3y_3.$$

Answer (score 0):

Expand the product
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{100}x_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{100}y_j\right)$$
and you will get the meaning.